# Detecting GSM activity

Tags: gsm

Is it possible to detect the GSM usage activity using SDR? I know that it's possible to do this using EMF meter, for example. What about SDR?

---

Radius of the range: 30-40 meters

P.S. ..GSM activity - by that I mean the usage of GSM networks by mobile phones, for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> P.S. ..GSM activity - by that I mean the usage of GSM networks by mobile phones, for example.

Depends. If you just want to see if there is any activity I suppose you could simply have a look at the frequency bands activity in e.g. gqrx. The frequency bands available are listed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GSM_frequency_bands).

It's possible to script gnuradio to watch multiple channels for activity so you might be actually able to watch the GSM band without really looking into decoding the actual GSM protocol on the fly. But that really depends on the capabilities of your SDR device.

Comment: Thus, the activity in FM band doesn't differ from the activity in GSM band, right?

Comment: Since GSM-data is transferred using a combination of time-multiplexing and frequency-multiplexing I am pretty confident (without having actually tried) that you can at least see if there is activity at all. So yes it differs but on the abstract level of "is there something going on?" it should not matter.